# How to draw a bitmap on a canvas on the whole screen?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

In my app I need to draw a Bitmap on th ewhole screen. For some reason when I'm drawing a bitmap, only part of the Bitmap is loading on a part of the screen. In other words, not the whole picture is showing on the screen. Here's a piece of my code were I draw the Bitmap:

```
byte[]byteArray=getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap tmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);

operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(operation);
Paint paint = new Paint();
tmp.setDensity(c.getDensity());

c.drawBitmap(tmp, 0f, 0f, paint);
tmp.recycle();
```

And:

```
private void drawOverlays() {
    Canvas c = null;
    try {
        c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized (holder) {
            if (c != null)
                c.drawBitmap(operation, 0, 0, null); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SurfaceView", "Error drawing frame", e);
    } finally {
        // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
        // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
        // inconsistent state
        if (c != null) {
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to get width and height of your device then scale your image to that dimension and display it on canvas.

Here is the modification of your code.

```
//add this code before your code
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

//your code with modification
byte[]byteArray=getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap tmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(operation);
Paint paint = new Paint();
tmp.setDensity(c.getDensity());
c.drawBitmap(tmp, 0f, 0f, paint);
tmp.recycle();
```

Now it will fill your whole screen, make sure you applied the canvas into whole screen.

Comment: I know it has been a while but I really need to fix a problem I'm having. for some reason when I'm sending the Bitmap operation and displaying it, it's only showing the left-top quarter of the pic.

Comment: have you tried this code? what width and height parameter you gave to your canvas in your xml file?

Comment: I found the problem in my code, I had to set tmp to the same sizes, the only problem I still have is that the buttom part of my pic is cut off (on my Moto G2)

Comment: please comment this line `tmp.setDensity(c.getDensity());` and try again.